# On Differentiable Functions (Khan Academy)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

I am learning Khan Academy Calculus, specifically how to tell when the graph of a function is differentiable or not. Khan Academy tells me that a point on the graph of is not differentiable when: 
[image]

But I don't get why 2. and 3. are true.  For 2, say we have a vertical tangent line for function 1/x^2 [image]

Would it not be continuous here? And therefore, wouldn't there be at least the chance that it's differentiable? Can someone please explain to me why a function is never differentiable at the vertical asymptote?

For 3, why would a function not be differentiable when it has a sharp turn? I don't get this either. Can someone please explain?

Comment: For 2. Do you the slope of a vertical line? For 3.  $\lim_{a^-} f'(x)\neq\lim_{a^+} f'(x)$ which is the basic condition for differentiability.

Comment: At $x=0$ the function isn’t defined, so the arrangement of number, symbol and words “$f$ is not continuous at $x=0$” isn’t even a statement at all, so it couldn’t be either wrong or false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your given function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ this is not differentiable at 0 since the function isn't even continuous there since at 0 it is undefined. It approaches infinity from either side leading to a infinite gradient on either side but AT 0 it does not exist. 
For (3) I would think a better way of saying this is a 'kink' for example take $f(x)=|x|$. This is not differentiable at 0 since from 0+ we have gradient 1, and -1 from 0-. Or you can think about drawing lots of tangents at the kink, they all look like tangents but are a all different lines so it is not differentiable.

Comment: Oh right. Okay last question. How about for 3? Why would a function not be differentiable when there's a "sharp turn"?

Comment: This is explained above, a very sharp turn means i can find lots of tangent lines so it would not be differentiable.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'll accept this answer in a minute.

Comment: Also, we want the limit to exist that is f(x)-f(0)/x as x goes to 0. That is why f(0) existing is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

At $x=0$ the function isn’t defined, so the arrangement of number, symbol and words “$f$ is not continuous at $x=0$.” isn’t even a statement at all, so it can be neither wrong nor right.